# Opencart vqmod and override engine work together

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Can Opencart extension vqmod and override engine work together?
I had required both extension in my opencart store apllication as both are conflict in it.

Comment: Elaborate the things .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can! Before you install the Override Engine, make sure you have cleared the OCmod and VQmod caches first.

If you use the VQmod from [vqmod.com](http://www.vcqmod.com), remove the following files:

> vqmod/vqcache/*
> vqmod/*.cache
>
> And clear the OCmod cache via 'Extensions > Modifications > Clear'

If you use the [Integrated VQmod for OpenCart 2](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501):

> Then just clear the OCmod cache via 'Extensions > Modifications > Clear'